# Updating global variable locally in Javascript

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, global-variables, variable-assignment

I started to learn Backbone.js library by implementing a simple project. After seeing a few tutorials, I produced the code which is show below. I am aware that it might not look perfect since I am new to javascript development.

So the below, I am fetching the list of nationalities from the API and then getting the number of students from those specific countries. This seems clear for the time being but the problem is, I need to get the total students per nationality which is why there is a counter in the second collection fetch function. The problem I am facing is about Javascript. Basically, defining "total" globally and updating it locally is what I need to do. I have come across to many threads similar to this one but to be honest didn't understand well enough to reproduce my own solution. Once again, my question is how I can re-engineer this code so that I can update the value of the variable "total" locally and then use the updated result outside of the inner fetch function. I appreciate your answers and advice. Thanks in advance.

```
    $.ajaxSetup({
    crossDomain : true,
    cache : false,
    contentType : "application/json",
    dataType : "json"
});

var baseURL = "http://lucalongo.eu:80/courses/2014-2015/questionnaireDIT/app/index.php";


var mModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var cNationality = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: mModel,
    url: this.baseURL + "/nationalities"
});

var cStudent = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : mModel,
    initialize : function(models, options) {
        this.url = "http://lucalongo.eu:80/courses/2014-2015/questionnaireDIT/app/index.php/students/nationality/" + options.id;
    }   
});

var vView = Backbone.View.extend({

    render: function(){
    var total = 0;
    this.collection = new cNationality();
    this.collection.fetch({
        success: function(c){
            _.each(c.models, function(col) {
               var nationalDesc = col.toJSON().description;
               var nationalID = col.toJSON().id;
               var studentNationality = new cStudent([], {id : nationalID});
                studentNationality.fetch({
                  success: function(c){
                      //console.log(nationalDesc + ": " + c.length);
                       total = total + c.length;
                      console.log(total);
                  }
               }); 
            });

        }
      });
        console.log("Total:" total); // still displays 0
    }
});


var v = new vView();
v.render();
Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
```

Comment: So you order a delivery pizza on the phone. You try to eat the pizza before it is delivered. It is asynchronous, you are reading the value before it is set. That is why there is a success method.

Comment: That's why I posted this question :) I would like to learn how can I change this code in order to get it working. Thanks

Comment: The point of Backbone is to have your AJAX response data automatically turned into model data. You should not have to be parsing your JSON response in your success handler.

Comment: After reviewing your code a little more closely, I realize that my previous comment wasn't totally on the mark. Regardless, the code you have in your view is definitely in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

Backbone tries to promote an event driven approach.
I think that you will ultimately end up with an event aggregator;

```
window.APP = {};
APP.vent = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);

APP.vent.on("update:counter", function(increment){ 
    APP.counter = APP.counter + increment; 
});
```

From the calling code, you trigger the event:

```
var increment = 5 //Just an example 
APP.vent.trigger("update:counter", increment);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using: `{async: false}`  // [Ajax-JQuery: Perform an asynchronous HTTP (Ajax) request](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```
this.collection.fetch({async: false}, {
    success: function(c) {
        _.each(c.models, function(col) {
            var nationalDesc = col.toJSON().description;
            var nationalID = col.toJSON().id;
            var studentNationality = new cStudent([], {
                id: nationalID
            });
            studentNationality.fetch({
                success: function(c) {
                    //console.log(nationalDesc + ": " + c.length);
                    total = total + c.length;
                    console.log(total);
                }
            });
        });

    }
});
```

Links that may help you: [Backbone.Sync](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync)

***Let me know if it works.***﻿

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the console output, you should see `Total:0` **first** then the expected value if AJAX call works as designed. this works as designed since the callback function in the fetch options will be called **after** the function call `fetch` completes.

According to your design, you don't need a global variable `total` since backbone collection supports `.length` convention. see http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-length When your fetch function completes. see http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch

Comment: Thanks. The Backbone documentation comes really handy to be honest while working. I use the length to get the total per id. However, I would need to get the total of all ids. More importantly, I am trying to work around the assignment operator. For example, the second total ""console.log("Total:" total);"" executes first as opposed to the previous one. I have read a number of articles regarding this. Ultimately, I am looking to find a solution to update the variable locally and be able to use an updated value in an upper level.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a way to manipulate `total` anywhere within the view. What I tend to do, in cases where I want a variable to be "global" to all my view methods is make it a property of the view. What I'm saying is,

```
var vView = Backbone.View.extend({

  initalize: function(){
    // Initialize your object property
    this.totalCount = 0;
  },

  render: function() {
  // Inside callbacks you will lose your view context
  // so save it
   var that = this;
   // Nested collection fetch
      success:  function(c){
        that.totalCount = that.totalCount + c.length;
        console.log(that.totalCount);
      }
   // rest of code
  }
});
```

Since collection fetch is a wrapper for an ajax GET (unless you override `Backbone.sync`) it will run asynchronously. If you want to run code in-synch with the fetch you can do three things.

1. Use callback functions like you do in your code
2. Use Deferred/Promises callbacks (very similiar to 1.)
3. Do what `@KimGysen`'s says: Backbone has a solid API for setting up and responding to events. (Marionettejs extends this API in very cool directions).